# "Post Merged" has caused two answers to look rather out of place

Tags: discussion, merged-questions

I'm not sure exactly [what happened here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7456462/1270789), but the revisions suggest that the answers from another question were merged in. However, we now have [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1355586/1270789) and [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1355579/1270789) talking about a completely different usage, so at first glance I flagged the first one as "Not an answer" as it seemed to be talking about a completely different topic. (I then withdrew the flag after checking the question history)

What should be the correct course of action in this case?

Comment: This is why I don't merge questions unless they are carbon copy duplicates (e.g. reposts by the same user).

Comment: @BoltClock probably safer yes. Also when it's not from the same user but a merge still happens, then I would recommend turning the question in Community Wiki, as there are now technically two OP, not one.

Comment: For all I care, we can just delete those answers. I doubt they will be missed. Although the fact those were the only answers to the merged question makes me wonder why it was merged to begin with, rather than left alone or just deleted directly.